# Can't reset my db connection in subclass

Tags: php, oop

I have 3 classes:
This is main DB class - if will be use in other two classes.

```
class db {
const DBHOST = 'Localhost';
const DBNAME = 'project';
const DBUSER = 'root';
const DBPASS = '';
public $db=array();
private $_dpt = array('fr'=>'','en'=>'_en');
public $db_pref = 'fr';
public $db_name;

public function __construct(){

}
public function connect_db(){
    if(!isset($this->db[$this->db_pref])){
        $this->db[$this->db_pref] = mysql_connect (self::DBHOST, self::DBUSER, self::DBPASS) or die (mysql_errno.' : Can`t connect to this DB');
        mysql_select_db(self::DBNAME.$this->_dpt[$this->db_pref], $this->db[$this->db_pref]) or die (mysql_errno.' : Can`t select this DB');
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    }
}
```

And this is my crud class:

```
 require_once('db.php');
 class crud extends db {    
public function __construct(){
    $this->lang = $_SESSION['user_lang_type']; // fr or en
    parent::__construct();
    if(isset($p['db']) && isset($p['db_pref'])){
        // I put here old db conn. to new object for economy
        $this->db_pref=$p['db_pref'];
        $this->db=$p['db'];
        if(isset($p['prevent']) && $p['prevent']!=$p['db_pref']){
           // if isset db_prevent - I connect to the project_fr db only 
           $this->db_pref=$p['prevent'];
           $this->connect_db();
        }
    } else $this->connect_db();
}
// reset prevented database
public function resetPreventDB($db=false){
  $this->db_pref=$this->lang;
  if($db) foreach($db as $k=>$v){ if(!isset($this->db[$k])) $this->db[$k]=$v; }
}
public function getData(){
    // this is shorted version of my crud query 
    // here I use link to selected db $this->db[$this->db_pref]
    return mysql_query('select * from advertice',$this->db[$this->db_pref]);
}
```

}
And here are my third class - it load data from selected database using connection of CRUD class:

```
class Advertice extends crud {
private $route;
public $cont;

public function __construct(){
    global $crud;
    parent::__construct(array('db'=>$crud->db,'db_pref'=>$crud->db_pref,'prevent'=>'fr'));
    $this->getList($p);
}

public function getList(){
    $q = $this->getData();
    global $crud;  
    // this didnt work - if db is FR it can be changed to EN
    $crud->resetPreventDB($this->db);
}

}
include_once 'crud.php';
include_once 'advertice.php';
$crud = new crud();
$crud->set = array();
// For ex. now I am in project_en database
$crud->getData() - will return data from project_en
$crud->set['ads'] = new Advertice(); // get data from project_fr
$crud->getData() // will return data from project_fr - but I call $crud->resetPreventDB() in  Advertice->getList().
```

I real didnt know why $crud->resetPreventDB() dont working - but I real wont this code, because this bug stop developing of all my startup. Will very Thanks for you understanding & help) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate, you are calling the function `getData()` , but in this function there is no reference to `resetPreventDB()` function.

Why the database should be changed?

Maybe you want to call the function `getList()` instead of `getData()` ?

BTW: It will look better if your code do not use globals, like that maybe:

`public function getList(){
    $q = $this->getData();
    $this->resetPreventDB($this->db);
    return $q;
}`

As a general advice - consider using any of the PHP frameworks around.
All similar issues are fixed long ago and are extensively tested by many developers.
After the initial learning curve, you will be able to develop at least 10 times faster.
If you need advise for specific framework - just ask.

Comment: Yes - using of PHP framework is a great idea, but project is so big, what we have no time to re-type all codes)
I find it - this bug was because php use in mysql_query() active db connection link, created in mysql_select_db. But yes - you are again right - PHP Framework its a deal) If you like - tell me what Framework will more easy to learn for me after CodeIgniter? Or what framework is more great on your opinion?

Comment: Well if you already know Codeigniter, then by all means continue with CI. Otherwise for big projects I prefer to use Yii : http://www.yiiframework.com this way you can really scale the development process.